# Should I avoid building for some android devices?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-4, nexus-s

In Android Studio, I'm building app with minimum Android 5.0 lollipop. I read that Nexus 4 is the minimum device available with Android 5.0 lollipop.

So does this mean I should ignore working on the screen sizes of Nexus ONE and Nexus S (since they are earlier versions)?

Comment: It does not mean there are not other band with the Android 5.0 or above with smaller screen size.

Comment: 1. Use layout that can response to different size. 2 create different resource based on screen size. See [Providing Resources | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Comment: I use constraint layout. I'm currently using an xhdpi ImageButton that I placed in Nexus 6 and looks fine, size wise but looks too huge on Nexus ONE and Nexus S.

Answer (score 0):

If you set minimum 5.0 you don't need to be concern about screen size, you need to be concern on android version. Your mentioned devices (Nexus ONE, Nexus S) are below 5.0, so you have to ignore these devices.But you need to be informed that small screen size's device can be above 5.0 (android 5.0). In that case you have to be concern about small screen also.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus aren't the only android phones that exist. There are a lot of manufacturers, and I guarantee some of those have a phone with a small screen running Android 5+. Even though NExus doesn't have small screens running 5+, that doesn't mean there's no one who does. You need to design for all screen sizes because there are even Nexus One's who are rooted and run Android 8 for that matter.

basically, don't ignore them. Design for all screen sizes, because there's always a rooted device or a different manufacturer with a small screen